# CSPRNG: Any time guarantees?

Tags: cryptography, uuid

Does a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator also guarantee, that the entropy is gathered in such a way, that the value cannot occur twice when generated at a different time?

I know it's highly unlikely already, but are there specific guarantees?

I need to generate a series of unique IDs from a CSPRNG that must not have conflicts.

Comment: I strongly doubt it. If you want to cover / nearly cover some range, [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) will give you this guarantee.

Comment: As one example - ["repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html). I believe it would reduce randomness if we know the new value is different from the previous value, thus this implementation doesn't have this guarantee (though it says "C **strong** RNG" not "C **secure** RNG"). I'm not sure if this is a ["negligible advantage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generators) - it likely depends on how many sequential numbers must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal (CS)PRNG assures you that the probability of extracting a certain value is constant and does not change over time, no matter whether that value was already output in the past.

For instance, let's assume  your ID is 32 bits long and today you extract `0x12345678`. What just happened had a probability of `1/(2^32)`.

Tomorrow (and at any point in the future), you will still have the same probability `1/(2^32)` of extracting the value `0x12345678`.

However, the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) tells us that if you generate 65 536 (=2^(32/2)) values, there is a probability of **50%** that two IDs are the same.

In other words, there are no hard guarantees the output of the CSPRNG will not be the same. Whether the chances are sufficiently small strongly depends on how long your ID is and how many IDs you expect to have in total over the whole lifetime of your system (special attention should be paid to security concerns when the attacker can generate IDs at will).

For completeness, all of that is applicable to any good PRNG - including the simplest coin to flip. Cryptographically Strong PRNGs have additional properties about complexity of predicting future or past outputs from any given output (it should be hard), ability to recover from compromise of the state, and ability to feed entropy.